# Java 7 on OS X not displaying anywhere but in console

Tags: java, macos

Ok, I went through the steps to install Java 7 on my Macbook from http://java.com and the applet the FAQ has me run after the install to verify the version running indicates 1.7.0_17 should be what I'm running. The java console indicates the same however, it looks like both are just showing me what version of plug-in is running. When I run:

```
jave -version
```

From the terminal it is still showing 1.6.

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

When I check the JavaVirtualMachines folder it only shows 1.6 and a find from root does not show 1.7 anywhere. I'm obviously new to os x and need some guidance as to what I am missing. I need to install the 7 jdk and set it as my default for all new dev.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, as I mentioned, 1.7 does not appear to exist despite package installer saying it does. 
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. java.com is the WRONG place to get the JDK. (I should've noticed it!) Go here instead.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: to be clear, you're downloading from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and not from here https://www.java.com/en/download/manual_java7.jsp ?